# Retrieve Sparql query response in json format

Tags: json, httpresponse, sparql

I am using sparql-client from https://github.com/thomasfr/node-sparql-client. I wanted to know if there  is a way to retrieve the query results in json format by giving some parameters?

My endpoint is an openrdf-sesame repository.

Currently, my response is as below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<sparql xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#'>
 .....
</sparql>
```

I used var r = JSON.stringify(results). But r.results show undefined.[image]
Thanks !

Comment: You can view the source online;  it looks like most of it is in [client.js](https://github.com/thomasfr/node-sparql-client/blob/master/lib/client.js).  It looks like the default accepted response type is already json (see lines 14 and 19).   How are the query results coming back now?

Comment: Thanks Joshua, the query results come back in xml format.

Comment: Interesting.  It looks like the client is a very thin wrapper that just sends a request to the server.  If you're _not_ using client.js, but using something else (e.g., a web interface (does openrdf-sesame have one?)), can you determine a way to get JSON results?  If you can figure out what parameter to change (if the endpoint can produce JSON results), then it probably won't be too hard to make the client send that parameter.  DBpedia's endpoint (Virtuoso) lets you put `&format=json` in the request…

Comment: Ah, how about this:  According to [this forum thread](http://www.openrdf.org/forum/mvnforum/viewthread?thread=2040), “You [have] to query the server directly as in the url below. `http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/memory?query=SELECT+*+WHERE+{?s+?p+?o}&Accept=application/sparql-results%2Bjson`.”  The SparqlClient constructor looks like it takes two arguments:  the endpoint and some options.  If you specify the `Accept` header as `application/sparql-results+json`, do you get a JSON response?

Comment: No, Accept header makes no difference. I used var r = JSON.stringify(results); and looks like I did get a JSON string. However, when I try to get r.results, it shows undefined.

Comment: No different with the client, or when submitting the request directly? I.e., what happens if you take a request like `http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/memory?query=SELECT+*+WHERE+{‌​?s+?p+?o}&Accept=application/sparql-results%2Bjson` (replacing the host as necessary) and paste it into your web browser?

Comment: From the browser, I get a .srj file. Inspecting it, looks like the results are in json.

Comment: Doesn't JSON.stringify return the _string_ of JSON text?  If you want the object from it, you'd need to parse that string, wouldn't you?  perhaps `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, how about this: According to [this forum thread](http://www.openrdf.org/forum/mvnforum/viewthread?thread=2040)

> You [have] to query the server directly as in the url below.
>
> ```
> http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/memory?query=SELECT+*+WHERE+{‌​?s+?p+?o}&Accept=application/sparql-results%2Bjson
> ```

The SparqlClient constructor looks like it takes two arguments: the endpoint and some options. It looks like you should be able to specify the `Accept` parameter `application/sparql-results+json` using that options argument.  My ECMAScript is a bit rusty, but I think it'd be something like this:

```
var endpoint = 'http://example.org/sparql';
var client = new SparqlClient(endpoint, {Accept: 'application/sparql-results+json'});
```

Comment: Doing this gives me, "TypeError : Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined.

Comment: Hmm… As I said, I'm not much of a JavaScripter, but [the code](https://github.com/thomasfr/node-sparql-client/blob/master/lib/client.js) shows `options` used in [`underscore.extend(requestDefaults,options)`](https://github.com/thomasfr/node-sparql-client/blob/master/lib/client.js#L66), and the [docs for `extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) look like that's the right format (although maybe it needs to be `{"Accept": "application/…"}` (with quoted capitalized "Accept")?

Comment: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)) works with or without the accept parameter.